# Clarification on Stack Overflow code license

Tags: discussion, code, legal, licensing

I have seen tons of posts on the license on the code used here on `stackoverflow.com`. A simple search brings tons of results but I still don't fully understand the license the code on this site is protected by.

If I make a commercial product and I use a code snippet from this site do I have to attribute it?

If I do attribute it is it legal?

Comment: See [What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25956)

Comment: Related: [Copying code to open-source bugtracking](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288413)

Comment: In short: consult a lawyer, but *almost certainly* any code you use from Stack Overflow is too short to be protected by copyright, and you can use the code freely under the Fair Use doctrine.

Comment: From the post I linked in the first comment: *That said, a snippet of code falls under excerpt category and thus should be free to use under fair use. Heck, we don't even support giant masses of code being posted, so to me, by definition, everything would be an excerpt. We're not sourceforge, github, or codeplex.*